# How can i plot a bar graph with two groups

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, geom-bar

My problem does not seem too complex though I could not find any answer yet.

I have 3 data frames from 3 climate experiments. For each experiment I have a list of events (month + Episode) that tells whether the event occured in Nino, Nina or ras situations.

I am able to plot a histogram using categories for each dataframe. However to make it more synthetic I would like to merge all 3 plots into one (they all share the same x-axis: months of the year). I thought there must be a way to address this issue, but the "fill" option from ggplot/geom_bar only works once...

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the example of code I can suggest:

```
month = c("Jan","Jan","Feb","Apr","Jul","Jul")
Episode = c("Nino","ras","Nino","Nina","Nina","Nina")
df1 = data.frame(month,Episode)
df1$Exp = "2000"
df1$month <-factor(df1$month,levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))

month = c("Feb","Sep","Sep","Nov","Jan","Mar")
Episode = c("ras","Nino","Nina","ras","ras","Nino")
df2 = data.frame(month,Episode)
df2$Exp = "RCP45"
df2$month <-factor(df2$month,levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))

month = c("Apr","May","May","Jun","Jul","Nov")
Episode = c("Nina","ras","ras","Nino","Nino","Nino")
df3 = data.frame(month,Episode)
df3$Exp = "RCP85"
df3$month <-factor(df3$month,levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))

# I can plot the histogram for one experiment
colours = c("Nina"="blue","Nino"="red","ras"="black","NA"="grey")
colScale = scale_fill_manual(name="Episode",values=colours)

gghist = ggplot(df1, aes(x=month,fill=Episode)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count") +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Episode",values=colours,drop=FALSE) +
  labs(title=("Distribution of extreme events"), x = "Month")  +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))
print(gghist)

# Quid: how to merge all three histograms working on df_4test
df_4test = rbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

Edit - added in data from user:

```
month = c("Jan","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Jul","Jul","Aug","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Dec") Episode = c("Nino","ras","Nino","Nina","Nina","Nina","Nino","Nina","Nino","Nina","Nina","Nino","ras","Nino","ras","Nino","Nina")

month = c("Jan","Feb","Feb","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jun","Jun","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Sep","Oct","Oct","Oct","Nov","Nov","Nov","Dec") Episode = c("ras","Nino","Nino","Nina","Nina","Nina","ras","ras","Nino","Nino","ras","ras","ras","Nino","Nina","Nina","Nino","Nino","Nina","Nino","ras","ras")

month = c("Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Apr","May","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Nov","Dec","Dec") Episode = c("Nina","ras","Nino","Nino","ras","Nino","Nino","Nino","Nina","ras","ras","Nina","ras","ras","Nino","Nino","Nino","Nina","Nina")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can plot all the data in the same plot using the following code.

```
library(ggplot2)
df_4test = dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2,df3, .id = 'id')

ggplot(df_4test, aes(x=month,fill=Episode)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count") +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Episode",values=colours,drop=FALSE) +
  labs(title=("Distribution of extreme events"), x = "Month")  +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))
```

[image]

Or you may use facets.

```
ggplot(df_4test, aes(x=month,fill=Episode)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count") +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Episode",values=colours,drop=FALSE) +
  labs(title=("Distribution of extreme events"), x = "Month")  +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)) + 
  facet_grid(vars(id))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ronak for your 2 suggestions. Solution 2 is close to what I am looking for but I was thinking to have only one graph instead of 3 subplots. Ideally I would like to see the facets appearing on one single graph (each month gets potentially 3 bars for each experiment and each bar is split by nino, nina, ras as it is done so far). The problem with your Solution 1 is that we are loosing information about the experiment.

Comment: @user16375442 Sorry, I don't follow. This already gives all the bar on top of each other. It is just that some month don't have all values (nino, nina, ras). For example, see `Id =1`,  `Jan` we have two bars on top of one another. Do you have an example plot that you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Ronak. My example is too simple, in reality I will be dealing with many more data leading to bars of much higher values than 0, 1 or 2. For the sake of easier visualisation of the differences it would be very useful to have the bars for Jan month corresponding to Exp.2000/RCP4.5/RCP8.5 side by side, same for Feb and so on and so forth, on the same plot.